# can I run spark command on python on my local machine to hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, cloudera

I want to run below code on my local machine.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession


def quiet_logs( sc ):
  logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
  logger.LogManager.getLogger("org"). setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
  logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )

#Spark Data Frame Jobs
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I have no installed `spark` on my machine.

this is make sense?

my purpose is load data to hadoop from my local machine?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load data to Hadoop from your local machine then you have to follow some approach.
One of them goes like

```
-> Send data from your local to Hadoop edge node.
Use SFTP for this purpose

-> 
Move data from edge node to hdfs using

hdfs dfs -cp

-> Run your spark job on hdfs then Load the data as required either in hive table or any use case.
```